# Rabinowitsch trick for multiple polynomials

Tags: polynomials, ideals

Rabinowitsch's trick describes the fact that for a polynomial $f \in K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and an ideal $I \subseteq K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, we have
$$
    1 \in I + (1 - fy) \implies f \in \sqrt{I},
$$
where $y$ is a new indeterminate.

I am interested whether there is a generalisation to more than one polynomial. More precisely, I want to answer the question "is $f \in \sqrt{I}$ or $g \in \sqrt{I}$?", with $f,g \in K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ given, using only a single ideal computation. So I am looking for a statement similar to
$$
    1 \in I + (1 - fy_1, 1 - gy_2) \implies f \in \sqrt{I} \text{ or } g \in \sqrt{I}.
$$

Is anybody aware of any statement in this vein?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Your suggested statement doesn't work because you could have $fg\in\sqrt{I}$ without $f\in\sqrt{I}$ or $g\in\sqrt{I}$.  This seems like it would be a general difficulty for any similar statement.